# How to switch to older version apps in playstore?

Tags: android

I want to know that when an user updates an app from Google playstore, Is there any way to go back to the older version of that app ?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383321/android-apk-file-re-activate-older-apk-file-in-google-play-store

Answer (score 1):

No, once you launch the apk on Play Store whether or not it's accepted by Google you must upload a higher version or change the app configuration, I mean package name.

Comment: `weather`?  I bet you meant `whether`, right?

Comment: sorry for mistake i edit my answer