# Publish an older version: Google Play Console

Tags: apk, release, google-play-console

I have published two versions of my app apks to Google Play Console.(1.3, 1.4)

But later I realised that there is a minor issue in my newest version(1.4) that I have uploaded. So now I need to un-publish the newest version(1.4) and publish the older version(1.3) again.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android APK file: Re-activate older APK file in Google Play Store](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383321/android-apk-file-re-activate-older-apk-file-in-google-play-store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was already answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/29549730

It's not possible. You'll have to rebuild the older state and upload again under a new version number.